# Pyinstaller executable giving error on start

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller, binaries

I am able to build a exec using pyinstaller but on executing the file using command "q_c runserver localhost:8000" is giving me error "ImportError: No module named **'django.core.management.commands'"**

My pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --name=q_c --hidden-import django.contrib.admin.apps -F --hidden-import cymem.cymem --hidden-import thinc.linalg --hidden-import murmurhash.mrmr --hidden-import cytoolz.utils --hidden-import cytoolz._signatures --hidden-import spacy.strings --hidden-import spacy.morphology --hidden-import spacy.lexeme --hidden-import spacy.tokens --hidden-import spacy.gold --hidden-import spacy.tokens.underscore --hidden-import spacy.parts_of_speech --hidden-import dill --hidden-import spacy.tokens.printers --hidden-import spacy.tokens._retokenize --hidden-import spacy.syntax --hidden-import spacy.syntax.stateclass --hidden-import spacy.syntax.transition_system --hidden-import spacy.syntax.nonproj --hidden-import spacy.syntax.nn_parser --hidden-import spacy.syntax.arc_eager --hidden-import thinc.extra.search --hidden-import spacy.syntax._beam_utils --hidden-import spacy.syntax.ner --hidden-import thinc.neural._classes.difference --paths .\env\Lib\site-packages\scipy\extra-dll --hidden-import scipy._lib.messagestream -F --hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs -F --hidden-import spacy.lang.en -F manage.py
```

My Spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['manage.py'],
             pathex=['.envLibsite-packagesscipyextra-dll', '/tmp/q_c'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['django.contrib.admin.apps', 'cymem.cymem', 'thinc.linalg', 'murmurhash.mrmr', 'cytoolz.utils', 'cytoolz._signatures', 'spacy.strings', 'spacy.morphology', 'spacy.lexeme', 'spacy.tokens', 'spacy.gold', 'spacy.tokens.underscore', 'spacy.parts_of_speech', 'dill', 'spacy.tokens.printers', 'spacy.tokens._retokenize', 'spacy.syntax', 'spacy.syntax.stateclass', 'spacy.syntax.transition_system', 'spacy.syntax.nonproj', 'spacy.syntax.nn_parser', 'spacy.syntax.arc_eager', 'thinc.extra.search', 'spacy.syntax._beam_utils', 'spacy.syntax.ner', 'thinc.neural._classes.difference', 'scipy._lib.messagestream', 'sklearn.neighbors.typedefs', 'spacy.lang.en', 'django.contrib.auth.apps'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='q_c',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this error